# Sequence in the django model access between model through foreign key to model how to fix my models?

Tags: python, django, url-routing, sequence

I have such a problem that can be turned into a lesson, a hack, with models, and with url-routing, it turns out
Need to be sequenced, that is, by url

Series / serial_slug / season_slug / series_slug /

But to get access to the seasons of the series you need so

Series / serial_slug / season_slug /

It turns out I do not have access to the 
series / serial_slug /

season_slug / no access to serial_slug in the Season model, since it is 
important for jango that if any model needs access, then the model must 
be on top of the requested momme, and thus access to There is no serial model, since it is below the season model, if they 
are reversed, it will not work, although the idea should be like this:

In the "Serial" model there is a lot of seasonal that is "ManyToMany" to 
the model "Season" that is the logical field there is a model Serial 
from above, then there is the model Season, then comes the Series, but 
it does not robit! In
 the "Season" model there are a lot of series, that is, "ManyToMany" for
 the Series model, and to get a consistent url, you need access to all 
models, that is, the "Series" model has a season "ForeignKey" for the 
"Season" model then The model "Season" has only 1 series again access through 
"ForeignKey", if you do so, then it will not work, because, he needs to 
have a model on top, to which the query is coming!

I think that this is a great idea for the Django series, namely the 
sequence, the dependence of the models, and also the sequence in the 
url, through reverse (), that is, the function get_absolute_url (), I 
have the code on pastebin, | `https://pastebin.com/RAJP6CNv` |  can you please see if I can throw The
 link to my question in stackoverflow, there something explained, but it
 did not help, maybe you'll understand, thanks for the lesson!

## this is my main url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^series/', include("serials.urls", namespace='series')),
    url(r'^', include("serials.urls", namespace='homeview')),
]
```

## this is my app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from .views import homeview, post_of_serial, post_of_season, post_of_serie

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', homeview, name='homeview'),  # /series/
   url(r'^(?P<serial_slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_of_serial, name='post_of_serial'),  # /series/Prison_Break/
   url(r'^(?P<serial_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<season_slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_of_season, name='post_of_season'),  # /series/Prison_Break/season_5/
   url(r'^(?P<serial_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<season_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<series_slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_of_serie, name='post_of_serie'),  # /series/Prison_Break/season_5/2/  

]
```

## this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
import datetime

class Status(models.Model):
    name                                    = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    is_active                               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp                               = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated                                 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return "|{0}| |{1}|".format(self.name, self.is_active)

    class Meta:
        ordering                            = ["-timestamp"]
        verbose_name                        = 'Staus'
        verbose_name_plural                 = 'Statuses'


class Season(models.Model):
    id                                      = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name_of_the_season                      = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    slug                                    = models.SlugField(unique=False, blank=True) 
    name_for_easy_access                    = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    preview_of_season                       = models.ImageField(upload_to="previews/preview_for_season/", default=None,width_field="width_field", height_field="height_field")
    width_field                             = models.IntegerField(default=150)
    height_field                            = models.IntegerField(default=150)
    number_of_released_series               = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    year                                    = models.IntegerField(default=2017)
    timestamp                               = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated                                 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    is_active                               = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('series:post_of_season', kwargs=
                      {'serial_slug': self.serial.slug,
                      'season_slug': self.slug,
                      })

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name_for_easy_access

    class Meta:
        ordering                            = ["-timestamp"]
        verbose_name                        = 'Season'
        verbose_name_plural                 = 'Seasons'


class Serial(models.Model):
    id                                      = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rus_name_of_seriall                     = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    eng_name_of_seriall                     = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    slug                                    = models.SlugField(unique=False, blank=True) 
    number_of_serial                        = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=True)
    preview_of_serial                       = models.ImageField(upload_to="previews/preview_for_serials/", default=None,width_field="width_field", height_field="height_field")
    width_field                             = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    height_field                            = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    seasonss                                = models.ManyToManyField(Season, default=None, blank=True)
    timestamp                               = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_or_in_proccess                      = models.ForeignKey(Status, default=None)
    timestamp                               = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated                                 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    is_active                               = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('series:post_of_serial', kwargs={'serial_slug': self.slug})


    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.rus_name_of_seriall

    class Meta:
        ordering                            = ["-timestamp"]
        verbose_name                        = 'Serial'
        verbose_name_plural                 = 'Serials'



class Series(models.Model):
    id                                      = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rus_name                                = models.CharField(max_length=60) 
    eng_name                                = models.CharField(max_length=60) 
    is_active                               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    serial_of_this_series                   = models.ForeignKey(Serial, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True)
    season_of_this_series                   = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=True)
    number_of_series                        = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    slug                                    = models.SlugField(unique=False, blank=True) 
    description                             = models.TextField(max_length=700, blank=True, default=None) 
    rating                                  = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=True)  
    timestamp_rus                           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated                                 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    timestamp_eng                           = models.CharField(max_length=60) 
    time_of_series                          = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('series:post_of_serie', kwargs=
                      {'serial_slug': self.serial_of_this_series.slug,
                       'season_slug': self.season_of_this_series.slug,
                       'series_slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s | %s" % (self.rus_name, self.number_of_series)

    class Meta:
        ordering                            = ["-timestamp_rus"]
        verbose_name                        = 'Series'
        verbose_name_plural                 = 'Series'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix these by putting string instead of class like

Change

```
models.ForeignKey(Serial)
```

to

```
models.ForeignKey("Serial")
```

Comment: I love you, oh, I've been waiting for this for a long time, but you can find out where you found it, maybe there's something to read?

Comment: haha. You can see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: sorrry) I'm a beginner) who knows a little of the English, and I taught django on video, and there unfortunately this will not tell) thank you very much, asked this question for 1.5 weeks)

Comment: help me pls  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519924/noreversematch-at-reverse-error-with-urlresolvers-get-absolute-url